# How to integrate this integral,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^ n} || \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} ||^{-k} d\mathbf{x}$? Here $k>0$.

Comment: Substitute $\mathbf z=\mathbf x-\mathbf y$ and $\mathrm d\mathbf z=\mathrm d\mathbf x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(\|\mathbf x\|)\,\mathrm d\mathbf x = \omega_n\int_0^\infty f(r)\,r^{n-1}\,\mathrm dr
$$
Where $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere.